# No cargan los estilos al momento de crear un virtual host en Laravel con xammp

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap, xampp

Estos son los pasos que seguí para crear mi virtual host

Accedí a la ruta  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
ahi edité el archivo Host  le agregué la siguiente linea

```
127.0.0.1 miproyecto.com
```

Despúes configuré el archivo `httpd-vhosts.conf.` que se encuentra en la ruta  `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

Y le agregué

`<Directory c:/xampp/htdocs>
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
allow from all
</Directory>`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/miproyecto/public
ServerName miproyecto.com
</VirtualHost>`

Despues reinicié apache  y mysql.

al momento de poner el dominio en el navegador, me carga de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si lo hago desde el comando php artisan serve me carga normal 
con la dirección http://127.0.0.1:8000
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del archivo **httpd-vhosts.conf.** debes apuntar el DocumentRoot a la carpeta "public" de tu proyecto, ejemplo:

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto/public"

El nombre que definas en *ServerName* deberá ser el mismo que asignaste en el archivo hosts.

Espero que te ayude

Comment: Ya hice el cambio, puse mi proyecto en la carpeta htdocs,si me carga la página, el único detalle es que no me muestra los estilos.

Comment: ¿Al abrir la consola del navegador te muestra algún error?

Comment: Ha fallado la carga del <script> con origen "http://miproyecto.com/storage/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js".

Comment: Es lo que me aparece

Comment: No sé si funcione pero intenta correr estos comandos desde terminal:

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:clear

php artisan view:clear

composer dump-autoload

Comment: En los comentarios de la primer respuesta puede haber algo que te ayude:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392188/styles-and-scripts-not-running-in-laravel